# How to create a an image gallery with a short description below each image

Tags: views, media

I have created an image gallery using views and a custom content type, Photo. It has 2 rows of three images each. I have uploaded the 6 images via the Photo content type, added a body describing the images and then used the views module to create the gallery. However in the gallery only the images and their titles are visible.

What I want is that the title should be displayed below and also the description for images should appear.

Here's a wireframe of what I am trying to build: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGoFL.jpg

Comment: did you upload all the images to one content?

Answer (score 1):

Creating an Image Gallery Of images in nodes.

1. Add a content type to be used for the image gallery.
2. Add the image field
3. Add one node per image with the description in the body field.
4. Create a view of the type content
5. Add the fields Title, Image, Body (In this order so that they are displayed in that order itself
6. set the format to grid.

Now when you visit the page you should see the gallery as you wanted.

Comment: HI sir..no i have not uploaded all the image in one content..i have created a custom content type and done so...thank you for your reply..i will try to do that and get back to you...

Comment: hi again..i followed the steps but the title is showing first followed by the body and then the image..sorry for jumping the gun..it seems to be sorted..thanks for your help